# Differences in set -x or echoed logs of values from "$@" in bash and POSIX sh

Tags: bash, sh

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.  I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
for i in "$@"; do
    echo $i
done
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ scripts/t.sh a b c\\nd
+ for i in "$@"
+ echo a
a
+ for i in "$@"
+ echo b
b
+ for i in "$@"
+ echo 'c\nd'
c\nd
```

If I change the shebang to `#!/bin/sh` and re-run it, I get:

```
$ scripts/t.sh a b c\\nd
+ set -x
+ echo a
a
+ echo b
b
+ echo c\nd
c
d
```

In the bash case the newline is shown as quoted in the `set -x` logs and is not interpreted by `echo`; with `sh`, the value is shown unquoted, and the newline is interpreted.  Is this expected?  Why the difference?

Comment: That's actually a `set -x` difference. Same behavior, rendered to human readability two different ways: The POSIX standard doesn't say anything about *how* `set -x` is supposed to quote or display its output, so both implementations are equally valid.

Comment: ...though `set -- $@` is buggy on its face. You **always** should quote `$@`: `set -- "$@"`, if you want a true noop.

Comment: Quoting made no difference in the output.  I'm not sure it's just a "set -x" difference.  Let me see if I can come up with a different test case.

Comment: Use `printf '<%s>\n' $@`  if you want output that doesn't depend on `set -x`.

Comment: In this case, none of the arguments contained IFS whitespace or glob metacharacters, so you wouldn't see a difference between `$@` and `"$@"`.

Comment: The whole *point* of using `$@`, though, is to get the special behavior when it is quoted. Otherwise, there is no reason for both `$@` and `$*` to exist.

Comment: With your **new** question, you have a difference in `echo` behavior that has nothing to do with `$@` -- one that's already in the knowledgebase.

Comment: And btw, `echo $i` should be `echo "$i"`. Try passing `'*'` as an argument to your script if you want to see what happens otherwise. That's also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and will be automatically detected by http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: ...the `"$@"` vs `$@` issue will also blow up in the `./yourscript '*'` case, btw -- extra points if you have a file named `*` in your current directory so the first wildcard expands to a value that contains a second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Differences in `set -x` output

POSIX does not require `set -x` to display its output quoted in any particular way. From [the POSIX specification for the `set` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html):

> The shell shall write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it. It is unspecified whether the command that turns tracing off is traced.

...and, in [the shell command language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), `PS4` is defined thusly:

> When an execution trace (`set -x`) is being performed in an interactive shell, before each line in the execution trace, the value of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written to standard error. The default value is "+ ". This volume of POSIX.1-2017 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

"A trace" or "the trace" -- the only language used to specify the text that follows `PS4` --  is vague enough that both implementations are equally compliant.

---

#### Differences in `echo` output

POSIX `echo` is permitted to *always* honor escape sequences, without requiring `-e` to be passed. (Indeed, a fully POSIX-compliant `echo` is not *permitted* to treat `-e` as anything other than text to be printed, so bash violates the specification by doing so -- except when the `xpg_echo` and `posix` runtime flags are both enabled, which is the only time bash's `echo` hews to the letter of the standard).

Use `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` instead of `echo "$foo"` if you want consistent behavior across platforms.

Quoting the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) in full, with emphasis added:

> **It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.**
>
> The `printf` utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the `echo` utility as follows (assuming that `IFS` has its standard value or is unset):
>
> - The historic System V `echo` and the requirements on XSI implementations in this volume of POSIX.1-2017 are equivalent to:
>
>   ```
>   printf "%b\n" "$*"
>   ```
> - The BSD `echo` is equivalent to:
>
>   ```
>   if [ "X$1" = "X-n" ]
>   then
>       shift
>       printf "%s" "$*"
>   else
>       printf "%s\n" "$*"
>   fi
>   ```
>
> New applications are encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

The sequence `\n` is an "escape sequence" for purposes of the bolded language quoted above.